# Download / Parse Email with Python

Tags: python, email, download, email-client, gmail-imap

I am working on an email client and have run into a small problem. I am unsure of how to download the email messages and save them to the local HDD. I am able to connect to the server using IMAP4 SSL (with the code below).

```
import imaplib
server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
server.login('USER', 'PASS')
```

Comment: I second @Daenyth , please try to post as specific questions as you can, this is not a forum, yhis is a Q&A, please if you haven't yet, take a good look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Daenyth, no problem. @Trufa, thanks, but I understand what a Q&A site is. That is why I use it. I'll post the code in a second.

Comment: @ZacharyBrown: Sorry if that sounded rood, it wasn't the intention, I do still think that your question should be more specific (even with the now posted code), but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Trufa, is the question better now?

Comment: @ZacharyBrown: yes indeed. I have no technical knowledge to answer you so this may seem off, but I would also reccommend adding some information on what happens: exception? error? nothing? Also it is useful to describe what you think migh me be happening, even if taht might be plain wrong. Did I explain myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can list directories in your mailbox with `IMAP4.list`. To actually get messages out of a directory use `IMAP4.select`, and then use `IMAP4.search`, and iterate over the list of id's it returns. In your case you could do something like this:

```
server.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')
resp, items = server.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
for mail in items[0].split():
    resp, data = m.fetch(mail, '(RFC822)')
    body = data[0][1]
    print body
```

Read the docs for sure: http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html. Also agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282976/download-parse-email-with-python/6283659#6283659), read through PyMOTW's tutorial. In general it's a good place to check for tutorials for modules in the standard library.

Comment: Great! So this does display the emails. The only thing I am concerned about is weather this will work with providers other than Gmail? I plan to share a copy of this with a friend and they have a Yahoo! Plus account.

Comment: You'll need to select a different directory (obviously `[Gmail]/All Mail` is Gmail specific), use `list()` to see what directories yahoo uses.

Answer (score 4):

For simple usage examples, I find that Doug Hellmann's "Python Module of the Week" gives a good understanding very quickly.  See the section on Fetching messages specifically.

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/imaplib/